# eclipse scaling issue on extended display

Tags: windows, eclipse, windows-10, screen-resolution

My setup is one DELL XPS 13 laptop(3200 x 1800, Windows 10), two extended displays(1680x1050) connected to the laptop via a dell thunderbolt dock.

My problem is on the xps13 eclipse displays properly, but on the extended displays, icons and fonts of the eclipse are extremely large.

None of the following works:

1. different versions(Oxygen, Neon, Mars)
2. close the dell xps lid or turn of its screen.
3. set dell xps resolution to 1920x1080
4. set Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true

Comment: Does adding the line `-Dswt.autoScale=false` below `-vmargs` in `eclipse.ini` fix your issue? See also https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks

Comment: @howlger: No does not help on Eclipse 2021/06

Comment: @Kukeltje Telling it doesn't help doesn't help. There is no _Eclipse 2021/06_, I guess you mean Eclipse 2021-06 which is two releases behind. Please show screenshots of both, your DELL XPS 13 laptop display and of your external monitor.

Comment: @howlger: Telling it does not help is more info than the OP gave.... and yes it is 2021-06 (SORRY), but it's 14 releases in front.... (compared to the 4.6 link you posted) and no, won't do the screenshots (don't believe me?) Thanks anyway, have a nice day. Will try to find information elsewhere.

Comment: @Kukeltje It would be helpful to know how to reproduce the issue and what you actually see for different arguments. I believe you that you think you faced the same issue, even its description is more than vague (how many pixels are _extremely large_, does `swt.autoScale=100` and `swt.autoScale=400` give the exact same result, etc.). But unfortunately, that doesn't help track down the issue.

Answer (score 20):

This seems to be related to the differing scaling factors between the monitors. Eclipse seems to take the scaling factor from the "main" display all the time, instead of taking the it from the extended displays when you move it to there. I have an XPS 15 and have this issue.

Workarounds that worked for me:

1. Set one of your extended displays as your "main" monitor. Eclipse will now grab the scaling factor from that monitor, which should make it look correct there.
2. Set the current "main" monitor (which I assume is your laptop's native screen) to scale at 100%, sign out, sign back in, and start Eclipse.

The downside to these workarounds is that Eclipse will appear very small on the laptop's native screen when attached to your extended monitors. And Option 2 will make your native monitor not scale anything so it may be impossible to read. I use Option 1.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 4):

Change the compatibility settings for Eclipse.exe in Windows 10:

- right click on Eclipse icon
- select properties
- select compatibility
- check "DPI scaling" option
- select "System (extended)"

Comment: This, with "Override high DPI scaling..." -> "System" for Windows 11.

Comment: On Windows 10 Pro where main monitor has high resolution, extended monitor has low resolution: | Compatibility | Change high DPI settings | Override high DPI scaling behaviour | Scaling performed by | System (Enhanced)

Answer (score 0):

Ive got a similar Problem ...
my 3rd Monitor ( for eclipse ) is a 4k Display with 150% Windows Scaling ....
my main Monitor is 1080p at 100% Scaling
Eclipse is blurry af ...

Found a WorkAround based on Losati Answer:
Change Main Monitor to 150% Scaling
Start Eclipse
Eclipse looks pretty fine
Main Monitor -> 100% Scaling

And Eclipse still looks fine on my 4k Display

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to increase or decrease the scaling of your monitors from the OS (windowing system). For Eclipse 2023-04 (4.27.0) on Ubuntu 22.04 you can go to Settings->Displays. Then select the monitor that is showing too small and increase the scale [image: Setting scale to 200%]

Comment: I did try the solutions to modify the ini file with the autoscale options, but it didn't work for me.