# Eclipse text is way to big

Tags: eclipse

I've seen questions on here asking how to increase/decrease font size for the editor in eclipse but how do you change all font sizes including tab names, console output, and the text editor?

Comment: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts in the Preferences

Comment: @greg-449 My issue seems to be caused by eclipse always basing its scaling off the computer's main monitor "scale" value regardless of what monitor it is on. I wish it were as simple as changing font sizes but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by eclipse always taking the monitor "scale" value of the main display regardless of what monitor it is on. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656928/eclipse-scaling-issue-on-extended-display) offers a workaround

Answer (score 0):

do these steps:

1. On the Eclipse toolbar, select Window → Preferences.
2. Set the font size (General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic → Text Font)

after that you can increase or decrease you eclipse font

Comment: I wish this were what I was looking for. Unfortunately the problem is that eclipse bases its scaling on your main display regardless of what display it is on.